# Metaclass does not initialize new class

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

all! I have a big problem with my code. I try to write simple code as simple framework for understanding meta programming. And I have the next problem.

```
doc1 = Document()
doc1.id = 20
doc2 = Document()
print (doc2.id) # show 20, but it's wrong!!! It should be 0
```

This is my code list

```
class BaseModel(type):
def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs,  **kwargs):
    instance = super().__new__

    parents = [b for b in bases if isinstance(b, BaseModel)]
    if not parents:
        return instance(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    module_ = attrs.pop('__module__')
    attrs_ = {'__module__': module_}

    classcell_ = attrs.pop('__classcell__', None)
    if classcell_ is not None:
        attrs_['__classcell__'] = classcell_

    for key, value in attrs.items():
        if not isinstance(value, Field):
            continue

        print (value.__dict__)
        attrs_[key] = value

    instance = instance(cls, name, bases, attrs_, **kwargs)

    return instance


class Model(metaclass=BaseModel):
    pass

class Field:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self._value = value

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self._value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self._value = value

class Document(Model):
    id = Field()
```

What's going on? I think the main issue is **new** method in metaclass. Am I right? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish with your metaclass is confusing, although it is not the source of the issue. Implementing unique ids does not require a metaclass, it only requires a well-crafted descriptor.

In your case, your `Field` descriptor keeps track of a single value instead of existing pairs of instances and ids.

To fix this you need to keep weak references of the already taken values.

```
import weakref, itertools

class UniqueId:
    def __init__(self):
        self._values = weakref.WeakKeyDictionary()

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        else:
            return self._values[instance]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value not in self._values.values():
            self._values[instance] = value
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unique id {} already taken'.format(value))

    def get_unique_id(self):
        existing_ids = set(self._values.values())
        return next(i for i in itertools.count() if i not in existing_ids)

class Model:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        for name, attr in cls.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(attr, UniqueId):
                setattr(instance, name, attr.get_unique_id())

        return instance

class Document(Model):
    id = UniqueId()
```

### Example

```
doc1 = Document()
print(doc1.id) # 0

doc2= Document()
print(doc2.id) # 1

doc2.id = 0 # ValueError: Unique id 0 already taken
```

Comment: It's awesome. Thank you!

Comment: @KirillMuchow No problem. On StackOverflow, do not hesitate to accept an answer that allowed ot fix your issue by clicking the green checkmark on its left. This helps other users find helpful answers as well as provide some good reputation to the asker and the answerer.